# versionName of re-uploading app after previous version was rejected

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-console

Our app had been rejected because of *All File Access Permission* and now we modified app compliant with google policy. We are going to upload updated version. Our app version `5.0.1` was rejected and `versionCode` was `51`. But now I want to keep same version `5.0.1` and increase `versionCode` by one i.e. `52`.  Can I still use same `versionName` and increase `versionCode` by `1`?

Comment: `Version Name` can be anything you want, `Version Code` is something that needs to be incremented every-time you want to push an update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As @DarShan said, `versionName` in your `build.gradle` is just a label, you can arbitrarily name it. Such a restriction you mind is for `versionCode`. The `versionCode` you must set it larger number than the previous version.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdk 31
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1 // integer value
    versionName 'Version.2021-10-28' // just a String value
}
```